# UnicodeDecodeError while reading a custom created corpus in NLTK

Tags: python, character-encoding, nltk

I made custom corpus for detecting polarity of sentences using nltk module. Here is the hierarchy of the corpus:

polar
--polar
----polar_tweets.txt
--nonpolar
----nonpolar_tweets.txt

And here is how I am importing that corpus in my source code:

```
polarity = LazyCorpusLoader('polar', CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader, r'(?!\.).*\.txt', cat_pattern=r'(polar|nonpolar)/.*', encoding='utf-8')
corpus = polarity
print(corpus.words(fileids=['nonpolar/non-polar.txt']))
```

but it raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Analytics Practice/Social Media Analytics/analyticsPlatform/DataAnalysis/SentimentAnalysis/data/training_testing_data.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(corpus.words(fileids=['nonpolar/nonpolar_tweets.txt']))
  File "E:\Analytics Practice\Social Media Analytics\analyticsPlatform\lib\site-packages\nltk\util.py", line 765, in __repr__
    for elt in self:
  File "E:\Analytics Practice\Social Media Analytics\analyticsPlatform\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py", line 291, in iterate_from
    tokens = self.read_block(self._stream)
  File "E:\Analytics Practice\Social Media Analytics\analyticsPlatform\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\plaintext.py", line 122, in _read_word_block
    words.extend(self._word_tokenizer.tokenize(stream.readline()))
  File "E:\Analytics Practice\Social Media Analytics\analyticsPlatform\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 1135, in readline
    new_chars = self._read(readsize)
  File "E:\Analytics Practice\Social Media Analytics\analyticsPlatform\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 1367, in _read
    chars, bytes_decoded = self._incr_decode(bytes)
  File "E:\Analytics Practice\Social Media Analytics\analyticsPlatform\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 1398, in _incr_decode
    return self.decode(bytes, 'strict')
  File "C:\Users\prabhjot.rai\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 269: invalid continuation byte
```

While creating the files `polar_tweets.txt` and `nonpolar_tweets.txt`, I am decoding the files `uncleaned_polar_tweets.txt` to `utf-8` and then writing it to the file `polar_tweets.txt`. Here is the code for that:

```
with open(path_to_file, "rb") as file:
    output_corpus = clean_text(file.read().decode('utf-8'))['cleaned_corpus']

output_file = open(output_path, "w")
output_file.write(output_corpus)
output_file.close()
```

Where output_file is the `polar_tweets.txt` and `nonpolar_tweets.txt`.
Where is the error? Since I am encoding in `utf-8` initially, and then reading also in `utf-8` by the line

```
polarity = LazyCorpusLoader('polar', CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader, r'(?!\.).*\.txt', cat_pattern=r'(polar|nonpolar)/.*', encoding='utf-8')
```

If I replace the `encoding='utf-8'` by `encoding='latin-1'`, the code works perfect. Where is the issue? Do I need to decode in `utf-8` also while creating the corpus?

Comment: Your terminology is off.  When reading, you decode *from* something.  The error suggests that the corpus (or some part of it) is not valid UTF-8.  Without access to the offending data, we can only speculate.  What does `LC_ALL=C grep -m 1 $'\xC2' nonpolar_tweets.txt` produce? (Maybe pipe to `xxd` or similar to see the bytes exactly.)

Comment: ... or the equivalent in Python -- read the offending line, then examine its `repr()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that in Python's model, `unicode` is a kind of data but `utf-8` is an *encoding.* They're not the same thing at all. You're reading your raw text, which is apparently in `utf-8`; cleaning it, then writing it out to your new corpus *without specifying an encoding.* So you're writing it out in... who knows what encoding. Don't find out, just clean and generate your corpus again specifying the `utf-8` encoding.

I hope you're doing all this in Python 3; if not, stop right here and switch to Python 3. Then write out the corpus like this:

```
output_file = open(output_path, "w", encoding="utf-8")
output_file.write(output_corpus)
output_file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)